# python read specific text and dump into csv

Tags: python, parsing

There are a bunch of text files in a folder which look like this:

```
Impedance = 92.01 ohms

Begin Post processing
Loss per inch @ 4 GHz = -0.481 dB
Loss per inch @ 8 GHz = -0.849 dB
Xtalk #1 (Conductor 1  2):
    Step response Next= -2.91 mV
    Step response Fext peak @ 5 inches= 0.18 mV
Xtalk #2 (Conductor 5  6):
    Step response Next= -2.91 mV
    Step response Fext peak @ 5 inches= 0.18 mV
Finished post processing


Target: 11.82.
```

The positions of these lines may change and they may be repetitions of these lines too. I have written the following code to parse them but I am able to only retrieve the first lines such as :`Loss per inch @ 4 GHz = -0.481 dB` but not the next Loss per inch line.

And `Xtalk #1 (Conductor 1  2):
        Step response Next= -2.91 mV` but not its next line.

The code is as follows:

```
    f = open(OutputFolder + '\_' + filename +'_LOG.txt')

    s = f.read()
    m = re.search("GHz\s+\=(.*)dB",s)
    if m:
        Lossval = float(m.group(1))
        print("Loss Value for filename " + filename + "is :", Lossval)


    n = re.search("Impedance\s+\=(.*)ohms",s)
    if n:
        Zc = float(n.group(1))
```

How would I be able to modify the code to capture all values except the `Begin Post processing` line and dump this into a csv file with the LHS as the column names and the RHS as their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.search` would return only the first match. To find all the matches, use `re.findall`

```
>>> re.findall(r"GHz\s+\=(.*)dB",s)
[' -0.481 ', ' -0.849 ']
```

Comment: Oh ok. Let me try with find all

Comment: So if i have some of these values repeated with different RHS numbers in the same file, will `findall` capture these too?

Comment: Yes. It would find all of those values

Comment: One last thing. The part where it says : `Xtalk #1 (Conductor 1  2):
    Step response Next= -2.91 mV
    Step response Fext peak @ 5 inches= 0.18 mV
Xtalk #2 (Conductor 5  6):
    Step response Next= -2.91 mV
    Step response Fext peak @ 5 inches= 0.18 mV`, how do I use regex to capture this? I would like to capture for Conductor 1 2 and 5 6 seperatey

Comment: `re.findall(r'Step response Next=\s+(.*)\s+mV', s)` would return `['-2.91', '-2.91']`.
Similarly `re.findall(r'Step response Fext.*?=\s+(.*)\s+mV', s)` would return `['0.18', '0.18']`

Comment: Is there a way I can get which `Xtalk #` does the value come under?

Comment: This would help me arrange columns while dumping into csv

Answer (score 0):

You might use readlines() instead of read() to get all lines in a file and then iterate all lines:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for s in lines:
    # To get the Xtalk #
    xtalk = re.search(r"Xtalk", s)
    if xtalk is not None:
         = re.split(' ', xtalk.string)
        num = int(a[1][1])

    ...
    m = re.search("GHz\s+\=(.*)dB",s)
    ...
```

Comment: The canonical way to read a file line by line would be (using this example variables) `for s in f:`

Comment: @PaulMcG Both ways are mentioned in python doc, thanks.

Comment: In that case, I prefer `f.read().splitlines()` over `f.readlines()`, as this automagically removes all those pesky trailing newlines.